# change data format from rows to columns

Tags: sql, impala

I have a SQL table in the below format. Every ID has 2 entries in the table for a particular date.

```
Input:
ID  date    rownum  subid   value1  value2
A   200911  1       X       10      20
A   200911  2       Y       15      25
B   201001  2       S       60      35
B   201001  1       R       40      50
```

I want to write a SQL query to change this to the below format, so that every ID/date combination has only 1 entry as shown below. The rownum is already included and the values should be represented so that rownnum 1 is displayed first and then the value with rownum second as shown below.

Output:

```
ID  date   row1subid row1value1 row1value2 row2subid row2value1 row2value2
A   200911 X         10         20         Y         15         25
B   201001 R         40         50         S         60         35
```

Let me know if something is not clear.
Thanks for all your help!

Comment: show data in tabular format..more create sqlfiddle and share..

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do as a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/45b78/11).

And for reference:

```
CREATE TABLE TestData
    ([ID] varchar(1), 
     [date] int, 
     [rownum] int, 
     [subid] varchar(1), 
     [value1] int, 
     [value2] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO TestData
    ([ID], [date], [rownum], [subid], [value1], [value2])
VALUES
    ('A', 200911, 1, 'X', 10, 20),
    ('A', 200911, 2, 'Y', 15, 25),
    ('B', 201001, 2, 'S', 60, 35),
    ('B', 201001, 1, 'R', 40, 50)
;


SELECT A.ID, A.date, A.rownum, A.subid, A.value1, A.value2, B.value1 AS r2value1, B.value2 AS r2value2
FROM TestData AS A
     INNER JOIN TestData B ON A.id = B.id AND B.rownum = 2
WHERE A.rownum = 1
```